# Iterate over a numpy array of dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to iterate over a range of dates I've pulled from a Pandas dataframe; sample below.

[image]

Code below initially threw the following error

> TypeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object is not iterable

```
r1 = pd.read_sql("select * from myTable",conn)    
...

dates = np.sort(r1['date'].unique())       

for i, d in dates:

   z_d = z[z['date']==d]
   r1_d = r1[r1['date']==d]
...
```

after googling, I tried applying the `iditer` numpy method, but doing so gives the following error:

> TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

```
 r1 = pd.read_sql("select * from myTable",conn)    
 ...

 dates = np.sort(r1['date'].unique())       

 for i, d in np.nditer(dates):

    z_d = z[z['date']==d]
    r1_d = r1[r1['date']==d]
 ...
```

How to amend this to loop over the list of dates included in the `dates` variable?

Comment: you probably want `for I, d in enumerate(dates)` or just `for d in dates`

Comment: `nditer` isn't going to help you here - it's more complicated to use, and no faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for d in dates` will assign `d` to each date in turn; `for i,d in dates` doesn't work because you can't assign a single date value to two variables (it is basically trying to do `i,d = dates[0]` etc.) If you also want the index, Python doesn't give you that for free with its `for` loop; you have to use the `enumerate` function to prepend the index to each item, and then loop over the result of that: `for i,d in enumerate(dates):`. Fortunately, `enumerate` returns a lazy iterator, so it's efficient; it doesn't generate all the indices first. But you get the same output as if it had, and you can see that result with `list(enumerate(dates))`, which will return something like `[(0,'first-date'), (1, 'second-date'), ...]`. So the assignments become `i, d = (0, 'first-date')` and so on, which work fine.

Comment: @[Mark Reed],  actually, stumbled into 'for d in dates' as a workaround after posting...using enumerate() is exactly what I'm looking for though, thanks.

offhand though, I have a vague memory of seeing the 'for i, d in ...' form without using the enumerate() though...am I misremembering or is there some circumstance where this is the default behavior?

Comment: You sure it was Python? The `for i,d in` syntax or something like it works in some other languages, I mean, it also works in Python if each element of your list is itself a list or tuple with at least two items, but if those tuples weren't generated by `enumerate` you don't necessarily get the actual index in `i`...

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop has two variables, so it's expecting two inputs from the array elements.  The errors are because it's trying to parse or iterate over the strings.  Change it to

```
for d in dates:
```